# Bash check if $var is in number range

Tags: linux, bash, time, range

I have made a bash function, which takes 2 arguments.

```
$1 = start time
$2 = end time
```

Both values are in hour fomat, so they can be from `00` to `23`.

The idea is that the functions takes the start and end time arguments, and play some videoclips in this time range.

I first came up with this:

```
TIME=$(date +%H)

# # #
#
#  Check if its time to play files
#  $1 = begin hour, $2 = End hour, $3 = folder with video files
#
# # #
check_if_time_to_play(){
# If current TIME is between begin and end time
if [ $TIME -ge "$1" ] &&  [ $TIME -lt "$2" ]; then
    # Make sure the folder is not empty
    if find "$3" -mindepth 1 -print -quit | grep -q .; then
        # It's not emty, play the clips
        play_files "$3" 
    else
        continue # It's empty! dont play the non-existing clips
    fi
else
   continue # TIME is not in range, dont play the clips
fi
}
```

But I quickly realised that this is not currect.

If I submit, say `$1=22`, `$2=05` and `$TIME=23` the clips won't play.

So I was thinking about adding an extra `if` in the last `else` statement.

Something like this:

```
# check for times where start is bigger than end (ie. 22-05)
if [ "$2" -le "$1" ]; then
    #and in here do some range check

fi
```

So inside this `if` I was thinking about doing some range checking, but I am unsure how to do this.

I was thinking something like:

```
if [[ $TIME -eq {$1..24} ] ]&&  [ $TIME -eq {00..$2} ]; then
    play_files "$3" 
fi
```

So this offcause does not work - so my question is: 
is there a way I can do check a `00` to `23`against a range of numbers?

Or if you understand what I am trying to do, is there a better way?

If you don't understand, please tell me - I will try to explain some more.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you simply check if `[ "$2" -ge "$1" ]` or the equivalent in Bash syntax (using `[[` instead of `[` allows for regular arithmetic operators etc)?

Comment: How about `if [ "$1" -le "$2" ] ; then start="$1"; end="$2"; else start="$2"; end="$1"; fi` Use the variables start/end in remaining script..

Comment: I didn’t know about that:) I will have look at it.

Comment: `[[ "$2" -ge "$1" ]]` has... unexpected results when the inputs are not numbers. Try `set -- foo bar; [[ "$2" -ge "$2" ]]; echo $?` to see what I mean.

Comment: @tripleee: I think you meant `((...))` syntax.

Comment: @mklement0 No, I didn't; but that would work, too (albeit the end result I think would be somewhat tortured).

Comment: @tripleee: Try `[[ 4 <= 5 ]] && echo yes`.

Comment: @mklement0 `<=` isn't supported in this context, but `>` is.  You can obviously replace `a <= b` with `b > a` with no loss of expression or legibility. But I agree with EtanReisner regarding robustness.

Comment: @tripleee: Yes, `>` is supported, but you were referring to "regular arithmetic operators" in general - it's not a good idea to recommend `[[ ... ]]` for arithmetic (including for the reason @EtanReisner states).

Comment: @tripleee could you give an example on the first comment you made? How would I go about using [[ instead of [ ?

Comment: This is tangential at best.  You can use `if [ "$2" -ge "$1" ]; then` or `if [[ $1 < $2 ]]; then` and as you can see, the latter is somewhat more legible; but there are caveats, as discussed above. Also, only the former is portable to other POSIX shells.

Comment: @tripleee sorry if Im being confused, but does this address the problem when $1=22, $2=05 and current $TIME=23 ?

Comment: @Bolli: No, it won't, and I suggest using `((...))` instead of `[[...]]` for arithmetic - see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, which uses **bash's [shell arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic)**, which offers **arithmetic evaluation using familiar C-style syntax** in several contexts:

- as a *test* or *calculation without output* in the form `((...))` or `let ...`
- as a *calculation* that *outputs a result* (arithmetic *expansion*) in the form `$((...))`
- when declaring *and* using *integer variables* declared with `declare -i` or `local -i`
- in other contexts where bash expects numbers, such as *array subscripts* or *substring indices*.

```sh
# # #
#
#  Check if its time to play files
#  $1 = hour now, $2 = begin hour, $3 = End hour, $4 = folder with video files
#
# # #
check_if_time_to_play() {

  # Make sure the arguments are interpreted as *decimal* integers
  # by evaluating them in an arithmetic context (-i) with prefix '10#', 
  # indicating number base 10.
  # (A leading '0' would cause intepretation as *octal*.)
  local -i hourNow=10#$1 startHour=10#$2 endHour=10#$3 play
  local dir=$4

  # Make sure the folder is not empty.
  if ! find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -print -quit | grep -q .; then
    return # It's empty! Don't play the non-existing clips. 
  fi

  # Determine if current hour is between begin and end time.
  play=0
  if (( startHour < endHour )); then
    if (( hourNow >= startHour && hourNow < endHour )); then
      play=1
    fi
  else # startHour > endHour: overnight hours
    if (( hourNow >= startHour || hourNow < endHour )); then
      play=1
    fi
  fi

  if (( play )); then
    # Play the clips
    play_files "$dir" 
  else
     : # Current hour is not in range, don't play the clips.
  fi
}
```

Sample invocations:

```
check_if_time_to_play $(date +%H) 22 05 .

# Hard-coded, to test logic 
check_if_time_to_play 23 22 05 .
check_if_time_to_play 11 10 18 .
```

- Note that I've made the current hour of day the 1st argument. (Also, it's better to avoid all-uppercase shell variable names such as `TIME` to avoid conflicts with environment or special shell variables).
- `$((...))` *outputs* the result of a calculation, whereas `((...))` interprets the result as a *test*.
- The case of the start time > end time (overnight) time frame is handled in a separate `if` branch, where the current hour must be *either* later than the start hour *or* earlier than the (next-morning) end hour.

Comment: This is an awesome answer mklement0 ! I'm currently testing it out (and learning) :) I can see you changed the  hourNow > startHour to  hourNow >= startHour, which I also noted. Seams like its working perfectly now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I will test some more and mark as answer when I am done. Really helpful answer! Thanks again. Also I moved the "check if folder is empty" if statement to the very beginning of the function, so it doesnt have to process all the rest, if the folder is empty.

Comment: @Bolli: My pleasure, glad it worked for you. I've cleaned up the answer a bit after you accepted it: simplified argument treatment, better background information, moved the empty-folder test to the top, as you suggested.

Comment: Really big thanks, its working exactly as I want now, and I learned some bash at the same time! :) Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use full dates? GNU `date` (the one available on Linux) has a nifty `-d` switch which lets you print arbitrary times. If you give it an hour, it will print the full date for that hour *today*:

```
$ date -d 23:00
Tue Mar 24 23:00:00 EET 2015
```

You can tell it to print the time in seconds since the epoch for easy comparison:

```
$ date -d 23:00 +%s
1427230800
```

Finally, you can assume that if the end date is smaller than the start date, then that end date refers to tomorrow. With that in mind, a working version of your script could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
TIME=$(date +%s)

check_if_time_to_play(){
# If current TIME is between begin and end time
if [ $TIME -ge "$1" ] &&  [ $TIME -lt  "$2" ]; then
    # Make sure the folder is not empty
    if find "$3" -mindepth 1 -print -quit | grep -q .; then
        # It's not emty, play the clips
        #play_files "$3" 
        echo playing
    fi
else
    echo "Out of range: $TIME : $1 : $2"
fi

} 
## Get the start and end times
start="$(date -d "$1" +%s)"
end="$(date -d "$2" +%s)"

## Deal with end times that are smaller than start times.
## We will assume that they refer to tomorrow's date.
[ "$start" -gt "$end" ] && end="$(date -d "$2 + 1 day" +%s)"

check_if_time_to_play "$start" "$end" "$3"
```

Note that I removed your `else continue` blocks since they make no sense in an `if` statement.

Comment: Great answer Terdon, thanks a lot. I really need to use the 00-23 format, is it possible to use date -d with date -%H ? I will have to read up on that. Gave you an up-vote, will wait with marking it as answer, until I see if someone can do it with the 00-23 format.

Comment: @Bolli you can use that format. In fact, you have to for the current version. You will run the script as `foo.sh 22 05 /path` just as you do now. The conversion happens internally. If that's not what you mean, you can always use `date` to convert from/to the different formats.

Comment: Ahh I see :) I will try to implement this into my function - I want it to run from inside the function, since the script is doing other stuff. So I don't want to call it with these params, The logic is indeed what I was looking for!

Comment: @Bolli then just put the date conversion step inside the function. Whatever you do,  it is always easier to convert to seconds and run the comparison that way. Just note that non-invasive date can't deal with that so if you need this to run on non-linear systems,  you'll need a different solution.